# How to write it short in less?

Tags: less

Here is my Less code:

```
i.icon-gps {
  .sprite(@icon-gps);
  display:inline-block;
}
i.icon-home {
  .sprite(@icon-home);
  display:inline-block;
}
i.icon-map {
  .sprite(@icon-map);
  display:inline-block;
}
//and many more
```

Is it possible to write it in one expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the usage is `<i class="icon-gps" ></i>`

```
i.icon
{
    &-gps {
      .sprite(@icon-gps);
      display:inline-block;
    }
    &-home {
      .sprite(@icon-home);
      display:inline-block;
    }
    &-map {
      .sprite(@icon-map);
      display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

---

If the usage is `<i class="icon icon-gps"></i>` *(thanks to @Curt's comment)*

```
i.icon
{
    display:inline-block;
    &-gps {
      .sprite(@icon-gps);
    }
    &-home {
      .sprite(@icon-home);
    }
    &-map {
      .sprite(@icon-map);
    }
}
```

Comment: display:inline-block was ignorred: .icons(@sprite) {  .sprite(@sprite);
  display: inline-block;
}
i.icon {
  &-gps {
    .icons(@icon-gps);
  } }

Comment: FYI - With this expression you could then also reduce the `display` properties down to 1. `i.icon { display:inline-block; &-gps { .sprite(@icon-gps); } .... `

Comment: @Curt, Thanks :). The previews version includes your suggestion, see piernik comment